# Intellij idea error when checking hyperskill project

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, backend

I am currently working on Hyperskill (JetBrains academy) on Java Backend Developer track. Every project that I try to check from the Intellij Idea IDE gives me this error:

Failed to launch checking

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':Simple_Search_Engine-task:compileTestJava'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':Simple_Search_Engine-task:testCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.hyperskill:hs-test:release-SNAPSHOT.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/hyperskill/hs-test/release-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/hyperskill/hs-test/release-SNAPSHOT/hs-test-release-SNAPSHOT.pom
> - https://jitpack.io/com/github/hyperskill/hs-test/release-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
> - https://jitpack.io/com/github/hyperskill/hs-test/release-SNAPSHOT/hs-test-release-v8-g6845035-132.pom
> Required by:
> project :Simple_Search_Engine-task

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

> Task :Simple_Search_Engine-task:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Simple_Search_Engine-task:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :Simple_Search_Engine-task:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :util:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :util:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :util:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :util:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :util:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :util:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Simple_Search_Engine-task:compileTestJava FAILED
> 2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date

My project: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xEV47YXdkVRUfB0JPSEkmcPtBbb5rbvJ?usp=sharing

Project from hyperskill: https://hyperskill.org/projects/66?track=12

I tried reinstalling the IDE or changing the project that I am working but the same errors. When I am uploading the solve directly on hyperskill website it works perfectly fine.

Here is also a video if it is more helpful: https://youtu.be/nvrpHuVq44A

Please help me! :D

Comment: It looks like there is no version of hs-test with the version "release-SNAPSHOT". Some more info on [this wiki page](https://github.com/hyperskill/hs-test/wiki/Initial-setup). Try modifying your `build.gradle` file to use a different version than "release-SNAPSHOT" of hs-test.

Answer (score 6):

Go to the `build.gradle` file for this project and replace the following line:

```
'com.github.hyperskill:hs-test:release-SNAPSHOT'
```

With

```
'com.github.hyperskill:hs-test:master-SNAPSHOT'
```

It seems that the `release` branch has an error, so change it to `master`.

Then, open up IntelliJ and restart Gradle.

Comment: thanks it worked !!! (you need to modifiy testImplementation)

Comment: after following this answer still problem persist then go to path specified in the error message and delete SNAPSHOT folder and try. it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please select JDK 17 as Gradle JVM in **Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle**?
After that, please ensure that JDK 17 is selected as Project SDK in **File | Project Structure**.

Comment: still not worked