# IntelliJ check problem during Hyperskill Kotlin learning

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I'm working on a Jetbrains Hyperskill track KOTLIN, it's my third project and I never had this kind of problem.
I found this post ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73025635/intellij-idea-error-when-checking-hyperskill-project)), and tried their suggestions (Which are the same that JetBrains give on their wiki/FAQ), but didn't work.

The project is:
[Unit Converter (Heavy Duty Step 4/5)](https://hyperskill.org/projects/70/stages/388/implement)

Here is my code:

```
package converter

fun main() {
    loopcheck@ while (true) {
        var conversion: Double
        print("Enter what you want to convert (or exit): ")
        val userInput = readln()

        if (userInput == "exit") break@loopcheck

        val (originalNumber, originalUnit, convertedUnit) = userInputSplit(userInput)

        // Validating inputs/Enums + exception checks
        if (originalNumber == null) {
            println("Wrong number")
            continue@loopcheck
        }
        if (originalUnit == null && convertedUnit != null) {
            println("Conversion from ??? to $convertedUnit is impossible")
            continue@loopcheck
        }
        if (originalUnit != null && convertedUnit == null) {
            println("Conversion from $originalUnit to ??? is impossible")
            continue@loopcheck
        }
        if (originalUnit == null && convertedUnit == null) {
            println("Conversion from ??? to ??? is impossible")
            continue@loopcheck
        }
        if (originalUnit != null && convertedUnit != null) {
            if (originalUnit.type != convertedUnit.type) {
                println("Conversion from ${originalUnit.plural} to ${convertedUnit.plural} is impossible")
                continue@loopcheck
            } else {
                // Conversion Calculus
                conversion = originalNumber * originalUnit.ratio / convertedUnit.ratio
                // Check if the units are singular or plural
                val preUnitCheck = if (originalNumber == 1.0) originalUnit.singular else originalUnit.plural
                val postUnitCheck = if (conversion == 1.0) convertedUnit.singular else convertedUnit.plural
                // Prints final text
                println("$originalNumber $preUnitCheck is $conversion $postUnitCheck")
            }
        }
    }
}

// Function to organize userInput in 3 variables: Number Unit1 Unit2
fun userInputSplit(userInput: String): Triple<Double?, Unidade?, Unidade?> {
    val userInputArray = userInput.lowercase().split(" ")

    val originalNumber = try {
        userInputArray[0].toDouble()
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) { null }

    val originalUnit = try {
        getUnit(userInputArray[1])
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) { null }

    val convertedUnit = try {
        getUnit(userInputArray[2])
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) { null }

    return Triple(originalNumber, originalUnit, convertedUnit)
}

// Function to set constant from Unidade for conversion based from User Input.
fun getUnit(unit: String): Unidade =
    when (unit) {
        "m", "meter", "meters" -> Unidade.METER
        "km", "kilometer", "kilometers" -> Unidade.KILOMETER
        "cm", "centimeter", "centimeters" -> Unidade.CENTIMETER
        "mm", "millimeter", "millimeters" -> Unidade.MILLIMETER
        "mi", "mile", "miles" -> Unidade.MILE
        "yd", "yard", "yards" -> Unidade.YARD
        "ft", "foot", "feet" -> Unidade.FOOT
        "in", "inch", "inches" -> Unidade.INCH
        "g", "gram", "grams" -> Unidade.GRAM
        "kg", "kilogram", "kilograms" -> Unidade.KILOGRAM
        "mg", "milligram", "milligrams" -> Unidade.MILLIGRAM
        "lb", "pound", "pounds" -> Unidade.POUND
        "oz", "ounce", "ounces" -> Unidade.OUNCE
//        "degree celsius", "degrees celsius", "celsius", "dc", "c" -> Unit.CELSIUS
//        "degree fahrenheit", "degrees fahrenheit", "fahrenheit", "df", "f" -> Unit.FAHRENHEIT
//        "kelvin", "kelvins", "k" -> Unit.Kelvin
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException ("Wrong Unit. Try Again.")
    }
enum class Unidade (val short: String,
                    val singular: String,
                    val plural: String,
                    val ratio: Double,
                    val type: String
                    ) {
    METER("m","meter", "meters", 1.0, "Length"),
    KILOMETER("km","kilometer", "kilometers", 1000.0, "Length"),
    CENTIMETER("cm","centimeter", "centimeters", 0.01, "Length"),
    MILLIMETER("mm", "millimeter", "millimeters", 0.001, "Length"),
    MILE("mi","mile", "miles", 1609.35, "Length"),
    YARD("yd","yard", "yards", 0.9144, "Length"),
    FOOT("ft","foot", "feet", 0.3048, "Length"),
    INCH("in","inch", "inches", 0.0254, "Length"),
    GRAM("g", "gram", "grams", 1.0, "Weight"),
    KILOGRAM("kg", "kilogram", "kilograms", 1000.0, "Weight"),
    MILLIGRAM("mg", "milligram", "milligrams", 0.001, "Weight"),
    POUND("lb", "pound", "pounds", 453.592, "Weight"),
    OUNCE("oz","ounce", "ounces", 28.3495, "Weight");
    //CELSIUS("degree Celsius", "degrees Celsius", 1.0, "Temperature"),
    //KELVIN("Kelvin", "Kelvins", 1.0, "Temperature"),
    //FAHRENHEIT("degree Fahrenheit", "degrees Fahrenheit", 1.0, "Temperature")
}
```

Every time I try to check my code with Hyperskill, this happens now:

> Failed to launch checking

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':Unit_Converter-task:compileTestKotlin'.

> Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':Unit_Converter-task:compileTestKotlin'
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':Unit_Converter-task:testCompileClasspath'.
> > Could not find com.github.hyperskill:hs-test:release-SNAPSHOT.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/hyperskill/hs-test/release-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/hyperskill/hs-test/release-SNAPSHOT/hs-test-release-SNAPSHOT.pom
> - https://jitpack.io/com/github/hyperskill/hs-test/release-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
> - https://jitpack.io/com/github/hyperskill/hs-test/release-SNAPSHOT/hs-test-release-v8-g6845035-132-v8-g6845035-132.pom
> Required by:
> project :Unit_Converter-task

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s

> Task :Unit_Converter-task:compileKotlin
> Task :Unit_Converter-task:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :Unit_Converter-task:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :Unit_Converter-task:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :util:compileKotlin NO-SOURCE
> Task :util:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :util:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :util:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :util:compileTestKotlin NO-SOURCE
> Task :util:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :util:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :util:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Unit_Converter-task:compileTestKotlin FAILED
> 2 actionable tasks: 2 executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reaching JETBRAINS support we did some actions. In the end, the problem was solved. Down below the steps taken.

1st try:

> Open build.gradle  in your project folder and replace
> testImplementation 'com.github.hyperskill:hs-test:release-SNAPSHOT'
> with  testImplementation
> 'com.github.hyperskill:hs-test:master-SNAPSHOT'

The build output after the modification changed to a different error message.

> Compilation Failed e: C:\Users\rafam\IdeaProjects\Unit Converter\Unit
> Converter\task\test\Task2Test.kt: (6, 1): Conflicting overloads:
> public fun authorsCase(input: String, isPrivate: Boolean = ...):
> TestCase defined in root package in file Task2Test.kt,
> public fun authorsCase(input: String, isPrivate: Boolean = ...):
> TestCase defined in root package in file Task4Test.kt e:
> C:\Users\rafam\IdeaProjects\Unit Converter\Unit
> Converter\task\test\Task2Test.kt: (6, 81): Unresolved reference:
> Authors e: C:\Users\rafam\IdeaProjects\Unit Converter\Unit
> Converter\task\test\Task2Test.kt: (6, 90): Unresolved reference: solve
> e: C:\Users\rafam\IdeaProjects\Unit Converter\Unit
> Converter\task\test\Task2Test.kt: (11, 13): Overload resolution
> ambiguity: public fun authorsCase(input: String, isPrivate: Boolean =
> ...): TestCase defined in root package in file
> Task2Test.kt public fun authorsCase(input: String, isPrivate: Boolean
> = ...): TestCase defined in root package in file Task4Test.kt ...
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':Unit_Converter-task:compileTestKotlin'.

After this error, Jetbrains support suggested new steps:

> Please try re-creating the project by following the steps below: Go to
> the affected JetBrains Academy project’s directory and move it
> somewhere else or make a backup.
>
> On the Welcome Screen of your IDE, go to the My Courses tab. Highlight
> the affected project and click ✕. Select Remove Course.
>
> Start a JetBrains Academy project by going to the JetBrains Academy
> tab in File | Learn and Teach | Browse Courses.
>
> After that, please ensure that JDK 17 is selected as Gradle JVM in
> Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools |
> Gradle and as Project SDK in File | Project Structure.

I've changed and updated everything as suggested and the build output changed AGAIN:

> Failed to launch checking
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':Unit_Converter-task:compileTestKotlin'.
>
> > Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':Unit_Converter-task:compileTestKotlin'
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':Unit_Converter-task:testCompileClasspath'.
> > > Could not find com.github.hyperskill:hs-test:release-SNAPSHOT.
> > Searched in the following locations:
> > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/hyperskill/hs-test/release-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
> > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/hyperskill/hs-test/release-SNAPSHOT/hs-test-release-SNAPSHOT.pom
> > - https://jitpack.io/com/github/hyperskill/hs-test/release-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
> > - https://jitpack.io/com/github/hyperskill/hs-test/release-SNAPSHOT/hs-test-release-v8-g6845035-132-v8-g6845035-132.pom
> > Required by:
> > project :Unit_Converter-task

After sending this output to Jetbrains they requested again to open build.gradle in my project folder and replace testImplementation 'com.github.hyperskill:hs-test:release-SNAPSHOT' with testImplementation 'com.github.hyperskill:hs-test:master-SNAPSHOT'.

This answer took 2-3 days to be replied. After that, the check worked.

Answer (score 0):

Open the *build.gradle* file in the root directory of your JetBrains Academy project and replace `testImplementation 'com.github.hyperskill:hs-test:release-SNAPSHOT'` with `testImplementation 'com.github.hyperskill:hs-test:master-SNAPSHOT'`.

Comment: It's exactly what I received from Jetbrains support, but didn't work.   A different message appeared showing compilation failed. Too long to paste, but in the end it's something like this.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Unit_Converter-task:compileTestKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

---
We still trying to solve the situation, as soon the problem is solved, I'm going to post the solution here.